# Polygons distorted in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

Configuration:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 (latest update)
2. Blender 2.75
3. Nvidia Quadro FX580

Comment: Welcome akshay :) I assume this is a graphics card issue. I'd suggest check your drivers.

Comment: currently using x.org x server - nouveau display driver. it was working fine 2 days ago..dont know what caused this error. also nvidea drivers arnt working so well with overall system ....

Comment: Not an expert, but AFAIK you have to decide. Either install nouveau or the nvidia driver.

Comment: you should file a bug report.  Just don't say "distortion",  it will cause confusion.  What you are seeing is usually referred to as "graphical artifacts or graphical glitches".  https://developer.blender.org

Comment: or you have two overlapping cubes. :)

Comment: Related, but not for Linux: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46769/2843

Answer (score 1):

try re-installing the drivers.. last ubuntu 14.04's updates are quite strange.. I had to re-install twice due of them in the last month.... remember to disable nouveau and purge other nvidia drivers (if you are gonna use the nvidia's proprietary from the home-page) before performing the installation, It could cause problems!

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "distortion" you are seeing. The screen shot is taken in perspective view, and looks exactly how I would expect it to look. I expect that if you press the <kbd>Numpad</kbd> - <kbd>5</kbd>, the apparent distortion will disappear.