# What's wrong with my meshes in edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view

What's the problem with my meshes?
running blender 2.77 on ubuntu 14:04

It's got these crazy shaded triangular divisions on all my faces? all models seem to be this way.[image: Cube with triangles]

Also, while i'm in edit mode the faces are difficult to select.

Comment: Try selecting all of it in edit mode and hitting W to bring up the specials menu, and selecting remove doubles.

Comment: just tried it no luck. it was like this upon install

Comment: This problem is likely to be [already asked](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33667/polygons-distorted-in-edit-mode) about. I'm not sure what could cause that, as suggested in comments there check that there's no overlapping cube (better recreate default scene and look there); if that doesn't help then this is a bug.

Comment: what kind of graphic card are you using?

Comment: Post your blend file and see if we can recreate the error.

Comment: If it was like that upon install it looks like a graphical issue with either your graphics card or graphics drivers. What are your system specs and graphics card drivers.

Comment: Gallium 0.4 on NVAC      I had a diferent driver - a nvidia gforce before installing ubuntu on my imac. im not sure what happened or why it changed.